# login screen show on seccond monitor

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, 19.04

First at all, take easy I'm a novice in Linux world :D
I'm using my laptop (L502x) and one HDMI monitor extended.
Built-in display is my primary screen and second monitor is extended. I always use HDMI plugged, but not ever my second monitor is turned on. In this case when I start my laptop Ubuntu show me login screen just only on extended monitor forcing me turn it on and logging...
After that I can power off second monitor and using my laptop ordinarily.
There are some way to force Ubuntu to show login screen in built-in monitor or who know in both at the same?
Ubuntu 19.04
Driver Nvidia-390
VGA 525M

uname -r:

```
5.0.0-21-generic
```

lspci:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 540M] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Dell GF108M [GeForce GT 540M]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 38
Memory at f0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
I/O ports at 3000 [size=128]
[virtual] Expansion ROM at f1000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI8Cz.jpg)

Thank you for all!

Comment: I would wait for others to see if they come up with a better answer to this, but my system has two monitors one of which is usually off, and the default greeter login greeter used to show on the monitor I usually have switched off.  I switched to using `sddm` (default for Lubuntu) which shows it's greeter on both screens, thus I see it when I have only one screen on. In your case I'd see if you get a better solution that what I did (ie. without adding another package, as I have LXQt installed too I didn't need to add any packages)

Comment: Thanks for comment @guiverc, I'm using gdm3. Can you tell me how do you did to switch? I'd like to try.

Comment: `sudo apt install sddm` will install `sddm` and then run the post-install script which will detect you have two and ask you which you want to use. If you change your mind, you can `sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm` (or `dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` too actually) and post-install script will re-run asking you again *which do you want to use* allowing you to change back if that's your wish.

Comment: I've not sure if I did it right, but didn't work for me. I edited the ask with a image about what I'm talking...

Comment: Hey @guiverc, I don't know if viable to you, but in my case I just install lightdm and now all things are working on. I'll post a image like solution...

Answer (score 0):

For someone who can has interested the problem was solved installing lightdm

```
sudo apt install lightdm
```

[Lightdm login extended monitor working perfectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u246P.jpg)

[gdm3 bug reported here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1760849)

Thanks for all